# Issue related to Adding Linq Variable in ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq

I have following LINQ statement:

```
    string[] str = { "a", "ab", "abcd" };
    var s1 = from s in str.AsEnumerable()
             select s;
    ViewState.Add("str", s1);
```

I added `s1` into `ViewState` and I got following error:

> Type
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   in Assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

How can I solve this problem and how can I add the LINQ variable into `ViewState`?

Comment: On a related note the ViewState is for storing state, i.e. selected value in a drop down, current page of a GirdView etc, not for putting data in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, because whatever you do want to add to `ViewState` must be serializable (marked with `SerializableAttribute`) as the compiler is telling you. The runtime type of `s1` is a nested generic class within `System.Linq.Enumerable`, which does not have that attribute.

One thing you could do is call `.ToArray()` (or another similar method) before adding the variable:

```
string[] str = { "a", "ab", "abcd" }; 
var s1 = from s in str.AsEnumerable() select s; 
ViewState.Add("str", s1.ToArray());
```

Of course, this is pointless as it stands because you could have achieved the same effect with just

```
string[] str = { "a", "ab", "abcd" }; 
ViewState.Add("str", str);
```

Overall, it's not clear from the example what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

You already have an array, so store `str` in ViewState.

```
ViewState.Add("str", str);
```